# How to use RECURSIVE TRIGGERS in SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite

In SQLITE I have a tree structured table called `Treeview` with colimns `(Tag, Name, Checked, FatherTag)`. Bassically what I want to do is to `UPDATE` the `Checked` Father element when all the child elements are `Checked`.

To do that I have a trigger that starts when I begin my recursive query. This trigger it's supposed to modify the `Checked` column when it has been UPDATED.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_update_father_Checked
         AFTER UPDATE OF Checked
            ON Treeview
BEGIN
    UPDATE Treeview
       SET Checked = (
               SELECT Checked
                 FROM NEW
                WHERE Tag = Treeview.Tag
           )
     WHERE Tag IN (
        SELECT FatherTag
          FROM NEW
    );
END;
```

Once i have my trigger on, i run my recursive query to select one familly of a tree and modify a `Checked` element.

```
    WITH RECURSIVE cte_Treeview (
    Tag,
    DisplayedName,
    FatherTag,
    NodeIndex,
    Checked
)
AS (
    SELECT t.Tag,
           t.DisplayedName,
           t.FatherTag,
           t.NodeIndex,
           t.Checked
      FROM Treeview t
     WHERE t.Tag = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.Tag,
           t.DisplayedName,
           t.FatherTag,
           t.NodeIndex,
           t.checked
      FROM Treeview t
           JOIN
           cte_Treeview c ON c.Tag = t.FatherTag
     LIMIT 12
)

UPDATE Treeview
SET "Checked" = "R"
WHERE Tag = 2;
```

And I am getting a:

> No such a table : main.NEW

Can some one please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't spam tag RDBMS tags... tag the one you are using only!

Comment: If you are using [tag:sqlite] *why* did you tag [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server]? I have removed these conflicting tags, as they don't seem appropriate here.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first post. I will be more carefull next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, to use a recursive trigger, you have to [enable it](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_recursive_triggers) on every database connection (Just like foreign keys):

```sql
PRAGMA recursive_triggers = on;
```

Second, you're trying to use `NEW` like it is a table. It's not. As [the documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) says,

> Both the `WHEN` clause and the trigger actions may access elements of the row being inserted, deleted or updated using references of the form `NEW.column-name` and `OLD.column-name`, where column-name is the name of a column from the table that the trigger is associated with. `OLD` and `NEW` references may only be used in triggers on events for which they are relevant... *[See documentation for those]*.

They refer to the *row* being changed, not a table.

So something like (Untested due to lack of sample table and data):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_update_father_Checked
         AFTER UPDATE OF Checked
            ON Treeview
BEGIN
    UPDATE Treeview SET Checked = NEW.Checked WHERE Tag = NEW.FatherTag;
END;
```